# Is there a generic way to use a try/except as boolean to make condition?

Tags: python

I want to be able to test if a condition/action/function is going to crash or not by giving it to a function.
How can I encapsulate a given condition/action/function into a `Try except` function ?

```
#This does what I want but it takes too much lines
def isInt(string):
    try:
        int(string)
        return True
    except:
        return False


#########################################################################
### This doesn't worked as expected but that the spirit ###############
def tryWorked(action):
    try:
        action
        return True
    except:
        return False

def isInt2(string):
    return tryWorked(int(string))

isInt2("12de3")
#########################################################################
```

If you tell me that you doesn't get it, I apologize, I'm maybe not really clear (but not a lot of people can understand the question I'm asking I think, "high lvl" functionnal paradigm).

Comment: Use `partial functions`

Comment: @peter.petrov thanks for your comment

Comment: You need to pass a function, like `lambda: int(string)`, then use `action()` inside `tryWorked`, because you don't want the return value of `int` as the argument to `isInt2`.

Comment: Basically you want to pass a *block of code* around. You do that by passing *functions* and calling them, e.g.: `tryWorked(lambda: int(string))`.

Comment: Just as an interesting historical note, [PEP-463](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0463/) proposed various try expressions, but it was rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `action` is a function or other callable, you need to actually call it in your code (i.e. have something like `action()` with the parentheses).

Here's one way of doing it:

```py
def tryWorked(action, *args):
    try:
        # Actually calling action with the passed in args:
        action(*args)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def isInt2(string):
    return tryWorked(int, string)


print(isInt2("12de3"))
# False

print(isInt2(12e3))
# True

print(isInt2("123"))
# True
```